# adding a custom button to outlook ribbon c#

Tags: c#, outlook

how to use **Visual Studio** to create a button beside "new appointment"

[image]

how the XML file should be?

would somthing like this work?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `idMso` tag in the Ribbon XML markup of the tab control if you want your controls be shown in the built-in tab. See [How to: Customize a Built-in Tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608593.aspx) for more information.

Find Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers in the following documents:

- [Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)
- [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)

P.S. As far as I remember you can't customize built-in groups. Only adding new ones to built-in tabs is possible.

Comment: I'm trying this ...

      <tab idMso="TabCalendar">
        <group id="GroupCalendarNew">
          <button enabled="true" label="TEST" showLabel="1"/>
        </group>
      </tab>

Comment: Do you get any UI errors? See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I get nothing, not sure what is the issue, but is this correct?

Comment: As far as I remember you can't customize built-in groups. Only adding new ones to built-in tabs is possible.

Comment: I will try to test it